# JS: Encoding/decoding optimization

Tags: javascript, encoding, decoding

I need 2 simple functions to encode/decode 2 small (8 bits) numbers into one (16 bits).

I wrote them in this way:

```
function encode(i, j) {
  const int16 = new Int16Array(1)
  const int8 = new Int8Array(int16.buffer)
  int8[0] = i
  int8[1] = j
  return int16[0]
}

function decode(x) {
  const int16 = new Int16Array(1)
  int16[0] = x
  const int8 = new Int8Array(int16.buffer)
  return [int8[0], int8[1]]
}
```

But I consider it can be done much easier, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This can be easily done with bitwise operators. Your code used the system's [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), but this one always uses little-endian.

```
function encode(i, j) {
  return i | (j << 8);
}

function decode(x) {
  return [x & 0xff, x >> 8];
}
```